# Listen with Javascript multiple CSS animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

at the end of the first animation I'm adding a new class with a new animation, how can I listen the second animation?

```
    function animate() {
        $ask.one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) {
            $ask.removeClass('bounceIn').wait(2000).addClass('flipOutY');
            //after flipOutY I want to initScene();                
        });
    }
```

After flipOutY animation its finished I want to fire initScene, how can I listen each animation on $ask?

Comment: may you make jsfiddle for view your existing code?

Comment: Replace "one" with "find"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try like so

```
function animate() {
    var evtAnim = "webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend"; 

    /* use on() instead of one() */
    $ask.on(evtAnim, function(e) {

        /* is it the first animation? */
        if ($ask.hasClass('bounceIn')) {
           $ask.removeClass('bounceIn').wait(2000).addClass('flipOutY');
        }
        else {
           /* unbind events and call initScene() */
           $ask.off(evtAnim);
           initScene();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want execute some function after the delay, you can use `$(el).trigger` to simulate a custom event, and add an handler to this event, like that :

```
$ask.one('...', function(){
    $ask.removeClass('bounceIn')
        .wait(2000)
        .addClass('flipOutY')
        .trigger('myCustomEvent');
});

$ask.on('myCustomEvent', initScene);
//                          ^^^
//                  call initScene() when myCustomEvent is triggered
```